# sending cucumber reports via jenkins Editable mail option

Tags: jenkins

please can you assist me.
I am new to jenkins, working on a POC for my organization. I have successfully integrated cucumber execution through **jenkins** and able to execute the scripts and generated cucumber reports using cucumber plugin successfully

**Issue:** 
I need to send the cucumber reports(reports are getting generated under(**C:\Users\username.jenkins\jobs\cucumbertest\builds**) send anyone of those reports as an attachment to my manager through Editable email option in jenkins.

please can someone assist me

Comment: hi there i have used the below format in default content for sending reports but the images and formatting are missing   - ${FILE,path="C:/Users/cc305906/.jenkins/jobs/cucumbertest/builds/${BUILD_NUMBER}/cucumber-html-reports/overview-tags.html"}

Answer (score 0):

The following approach worked for me:

1. Cucumber project's `pom.xml` have to include maven-cucumber-reporting plugin.Because we want to create report under Target folder.How to configure your `pom.xml`: https://github.com/damianszczepanik/
2. Jenkins Manage Plugin and install Email-ext plugin & Post build task.
3. Report files js, html, etc. in folder but I think if we want to send them properly via mail, their extension must be zip. So, we create a batch file and put it into `C:\Users\yourUser\.jenkins\workspace\yourProject`.
4. I use 7-Zip ;

   4.1 Open txt file in notepad,

   4.2 Put the following script into the file

   ```
   @echo off
   setlocal
   for /d %%x in (C:\Users\yourUser\.jenkins\workspace\yourProject\target\cucumber-html-reports*.*) do "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a -tzip "%%x.zip" "%%x\"
   endlocal
   exit
   ```

   4.3 save as `.bat` file.  For Example I have `new.bat`
5. In Jenkins choose Post Build Task then I write  C:\Users\yourUser.jenkins\workspace\yourProject\new.bat in area script
6. Then Editable Email Notification part Attachments part must be

   ```
   **\**\cucumber-html-reports.zip
   ```